# Why does Math.SE not show the user's reputation in the homepage?

Tags: support, reputation

See this image of TeX Stack Exchange:

[image]

This shows the user's reputation. But Mathematics Stack Exchange doesn't show it:

[image]

Comment: My page shows my reputation.

Comment: @Qudit math.meta.stackexchage shows but math.stackexchage doesn't.

Comment: Both show for me.

Comment: @Qudit it may be a bug of firefox. I use firefox 57(quantum)

Comment: I see my reputation on my page but, if I hit the magnification button a couple of times, then my reputation disappears and I see just my avatar. That's just some [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) trick. Looking at the font sizes in your screenshots, I suspect that you've got the magnification set differently i those two tabs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the result of your browser's zoom function; you view the TeX site at 110% of the original size, and Mathematics at 150%. At 150% zoom, there is less space available and the responsive design switches to mode which displays less information in the top bar. When you set the zoom to a lower level, everything should be fine.

[image]
[image]

<sub>(apologies to future readers for the blue freehand circles, which were needed because the OP used red)</sub>

Comment: [That's you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/295232). And according to Stack Exchange culture, freehand circles should generally be in [red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/295232), unless there's a good reason to deviate.